# How to change font in Dia and fix its font rendering issues?

Tags: dia

Excuse me for my probably stupid questions.

First, I cannot configure font used by Dia.
I couldn't find it anywhere in its scanty preferences.
The only way to change the font I found so far - is for the secific object, e.g. Flowchart:Box. But it doesn't get applied to the other objects.
Also I coudn't find anything on this in Google. I suspect that's because just few people nowadays use Dia.

Second, is there a way to increase the overall quality of fonts support in Dia?

Have a look at the screenshot (but please open on in full scale). Dia is on the left side and Inkscape is on the right. 
The font is the same - DejaVu Sans. You can see that Dia doesn't do hinting well (note the gap between 0 (zero) and 3). This is 100% scale btw.

If you have any ideas how to fix it - please share.

[image]

Comment: Step one: Make sure the antialias renderer is enabled, by default you get the legacy libart

Comment: Step two: Double click on an item in the toolbox to set default properties, of course this is still per type

Comment: Thanks Zander. First, antialiased was disabled as you said, but enabling it hasn't really change anything. I think that's because the issue here is not an absent antialiasing, but font scaling (which is probably perfromed by some underlying machinery). As for the default font - thanks, it worked. I would never fathom out to do this myself :)

Comment: Don't worry, I only found out when I was working on that part of the code one day - It's rather well hidden

Sorry that didn't help the font rendering